# Баг gulp-cssnano

Tags: css, css3, gulp

Баг gulp-cssnano. если мы делает так:

```
.border_radius {
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 80px; 

}
```

То при минификации этого не будет : **-webkit-border-radius: 8px;**

Если мы пишем так:

```
.border_radius {
      border-radius: 80px; 
      -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    }
```

то все сминифицируется.

Вопрос: как исправить или что лучше тогда использовать для минификации?

Comment: думаю, тоже удаляет "старые" перфиксы. а во втором случае, из-за лишних отступов, действует по-умолчанию. попробуй вот это https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-csso/

Comment: и да, что тебе так сдался этот префикс?)

Comment: @Alexey Kopantsev - Ну он для поддержки старых версий)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cssnano` использует `autoprefixer` для добавления префиксов на основе списка поддерживаемых браузеров. Есть множество способов задать список поддерживаемых браузеров ([подробнее](https://github.com/ai/browserslist#queries)).
По умолчанию префиксы [удаляются](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/69#issuecomment-144857220).

Код для добавления префиксов для 50 последних версий каждого браузера примерно такой:

```
var gulp=require('gulp');
var cssnano=require('gulp-cssnano');

gulp.task('default', function(){
  gulp.src('./src.css')
   .pipe(cssnano({autoprefixer: {
     browsers:['last 50 versions'], 
     add: true
   }}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});
```

Скармливаем первый вариант:

```
.border_radius{-webkit-border-radius:8px;-moz-border-radius:80px;border-radius:80px}
```

Второй вариант:

```
.border_radius{-moz-border-radius:80px;border-radius:80px;-webkit-border-radius:8px}
```

На вопрос не ответил, но ясности, надеюсь, добавил.

Answer (score 1):

Во, ответ от самих разработчиков:

It's not a bug; cssnano uses autoprefixer to remove prefixes that are no longer necessary. -webkit-border-radius is not used by modern browsers. If you need to support these prefixes you can pass the browsers that you would like to support with the options object.

```
{
  autoprefixer: {browsers: 'last 2 versions'}
}
```

See https://github.com/ai/browserslist for the available options.